# Parent Record Data Lists Always Visible or Only When Needed?

Tags: forms, data, master-details

I am rebuilding the interface for my band's web site. Currently, I have all main-level navigation in one, horizontal list. However, the navigation leads to some pages that have a defined hierarchy.

[Band Web Site Navigation http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4131428/stackexchange/RetroShockBandMainNavTabs.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4131428/stackexchange/RetroShockBandMainNavTabs.png)

The most-common pages I need to access, directly, are: Dashboard, Planner, Blackouts, Songs and Shows. The rest of the pages are accessed less-often.

When I'm adding a new song, I *may* need to add an artist, but not always.  When I add a show, I *may* need to add a venue.  When I add a venue I *may* need to add a city.

Every now and then, I may need to update the venue owner's name or phone number.

That said, should these parent pages always be visible or only on the pages where they are used?  For example, if I need to create a venue, should it be a separate page or a sub-page of the "Shows" page.  (Can't have a show without a venue.)

Even with that in mind, I would still need a way to modify an existing parent record (venue owner name).

With that, should these rare pages be listed under a "Utility" link?

Comment: can you add some diagrams or screenshots to your question to make it easier to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your site, it seems that Cities and Venues are supporting data for Shows, and that Artists are only used when entering Songs.

In this case, it makes sense to break those down into two sections. Something like "Shows & Locations" and "Songs & Artists."

Shows & Locations would have sub-sections of Shows, Cities, and Venues.

Since you seem to be your own client, in the end you should do whatever makes the most sense to you as you go about using the site :)

Comment: For now, I'm the only user of this interface, but I plan on expanding to other members as well as creating an online service.  Combining the sections in to Shows & Locations is the best idea I have heard.  Thanks